# Having Tkitner labels update if a config file line is changed

Tags: python, tkinter

I have 3 labels on my menu that display the file path of 3 different files/directories. I have 3 buttons that allow the user to change said file paths. If pressed the buttons will automatically update a config.ini file.

I would like these labels to display as a default value what is in the config file, unless that file is updated and then it would dynamically change to display the new file path.

Here are the 3 methods for my button commands:

```
def open_vend_direct():
    vend_directory = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        initialdir="/", title="Select file", filetypes=(("Excel Files (CSV)", "*.csv"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    parser = ConfigParser()
    parser.read('config.ini')
    parser.set('VendorList','List_Location',vend_directory)
    with open('config.ini', 'w') as f:
        parser.write(f)

def open_attach_direct():
    vend_attach_direct = filedialog.askdirectory()
    parser = ConfigParser()
    parser.read('config.ini')
    parser.set('VendorFile','file_Location',vend_attach_direct)
    with open('config.ini', 'w') as f:
        parser.write(f)


def open_log_direct():
    log_locate = filedialog.askdirectory()
    parser = ConfigParser()
    parser.read('config.ini')
    parser.set('LogFolder','log_location',log_locate)
    with open('config.ini', 'w') as f:
        parser.write(f)
```

Here are my 3 buttons and their respective labels:

```
parser = ConfigParser()
parser.read('config.ini')

vend_list_button = ttk.Button(optionmenu, text='Vendor List Directory',
                              command=open_vend_direct).grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=W)
vend_list_locat = ttk.Label(optionmenu, text=parser.get('VendorList','list_location')).grid(
    column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

############################
# row 2
vend_attach_button = ttk.Button(optionmenu, text='Vendor File Directory',
                                command=open_attach_direct).grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=W)
vend_attach_locat = ttk.Label(optionmenu, text=parser.get('VendorFile','file_location')).grid(
    column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))

###########################
# row 3
log_location_button = ttk.Button(
    optionmenu, text='Log Folder Preference', command=open_log_direct).grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=W)
log_locat = ttk.Label(optionmenu, text=parser.get('LogFolder','log_location')).grid(
    column=2, row=3, sticky=(W, E))
```

As you can see for those 3 labels I have the text set to reading the config file. Which means when I restart the program it will change but I would like for it to update without restarting.

Comment: You've said what you want to do, but you didn't ask a question. What part of the solution do you need help with?

Comment: I need my label text to change dynamically. I can only get it to change every time the script is ran. @BryanOakley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it you have three options.
Fastest fix is changeing label with

```py
ttk.label_name['text']="new text"
```

A better option is  useing textvarable instead of just text.

You define it as:

```py
my_text = stringvar()
my_text.set("inital text")
```

when defining label
instead of text = "blablabla"

```py
textvar = my_text
```

And to change label just use

```py
my_text.set("new text")
```

Third option is to use update function. Which would read your init file every interval and changed your labels accordingly. If that option interest you read thishttps://riptutorial.com/tkinter/example/22870/-after--